# Four base URLs for login/auth, grant token, grant refresh, and token profile?

Tags: oauth-2.0, servicenow-rest-api

What are the four base URLs that define the standard handling of OAuth 2.0 in ServiceNow?

1. **Login/Authorization URL**, `response_type=code`. Redirects to service login page to authenticate by the client providing their username and password.
2. **Get an Access Token URL**, paired response to the previous **Login/Authorization URL**, with the previously returned code, `grant_type=token&code=***`
3. **Refresh Access Token URL**, `grant_type=refresh_token`
4. **Access Token Info/Profile URL**, providing details about currently active access token.

ServiceNow OAuth documentation focuses on `grant_type=password`, and I am not interested in this approach.